# On-premises to Azure SQL server-duplicate primary key error

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline in Azure Data Factory that copies data from On-Premises SQL Server Database to Azure SQL Server Database incrementally which runs every night. A couple of days back I see the below error and it's repeating since then. I verified in source and there are no duplicate values. The primary key constraint is applied there. On Target there is no record with the specified values. But still, it is throwing this error. Not sure what is causing the error and how to fix it? Not sure why it is throwing an error for inserting from the source when we are just trying to read from the source.

> ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint '$0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.. The duplicate key value is (X596LAMONT, 34, 274274, 1). The statement has been terminated.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint '$0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.. The duplicate key value is (X596LAMONT, 34, 274274, 1). The statement has been terminated. ,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=2627,Class=14,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=14,Number=2627,State=1,Message=Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint '$0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.. The duplicate key value is (X596LAMONT, 34, 274274, 1).,},{Class=0,Number=3621,State=0,Message=The statement has been terminated.,},],'

When I had a similar issue earlier, we truncated and reloaded the whole table. that was on a different table. But after we did that truncate and reloading since then we didn't see any issue with those tables.

We know that there were some updates on the source side that happened recently which may have impacted that table but we don't know for sure.

We can try truncating and reloading but we want to know what is the reason for this. Is it some bug on azure data factory or if we are missing details on how it works internally and we must be aware of it for next time.

Comment: create a new  table with same structure and copy data from existing but without the primary key and see what kind of duplicates you will insert there, and then take it from there

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of error you are getting is when attempting to insert a record into the target table, it displays that the primary key constraint is being broken.

- The duplicate key value that is the problem is displayed in the error message.
- It's conceivable that duplicate records in the source database are the root of this problem.

But as you said you verified your tables, and it doesn't have any duplicated rows so to get the information of the error causing rows you can follow below:

**You can also enable logging of the incompatible rows to help identify the root cause of the incompatibility.**

Go to Copy activity settings >> check enable logging >> connect blob storage linked service. as show in below image.

[image]